# Fabric peer nodes won't stay up

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I've been working through https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gettingstarted/ on Windows 10. Starting the network (with docker-compose -f docker-compose-gettingstarted.yml up) gives me initially cli, ca, orderer and peers 0,1,2 but after about 30 second peer0 disappears (as seen from docker ps).

I can restart peer0 with "docker start peer0" but after 20-30 seconds peers 1 and 2 in turn disappear.

I haven't changed the yml in any way (no changes were specified in the doc)

Has anyone seen anything similar? I am a newbie don't know what to try next or where to look for any additional information.

The results.txt has the expected
SUCCESSFUL CHANNEL CREATION
SUCCESSFUL JOIN CHANNEL on PEER0
SUCCESSFUL JOIN CHANNEL on PEER1
SUCCESSFUL JOIN CHANNEL on PEER2

and there is a genesis block, again as indicated in the doc.

This behaviour is repeatable - happens every time. As a result I can't try to do anything interesting like deploy chaincode. Any help or suggestions would be most welcome!

Comment: This is following the instructions in https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gettingstarted/ BTW.

Comment: Is there anything in the logs from the peers that won't stay up? The tutorial works flawlessly for me, so it is likely an environmental problem.

Comment: Thanks for responding to this one. Since it worked without problems for you, I have checked through all the environment one more time, and I *think* this may have been a docker problem - I have uninstalled docker and reinstalled it (not a trivial thing in itself, see https://forums.docker.com/t/cannot-uninstall-docker-for-windows/15661/13) and now the fabric tutorial can be worked through successfully without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this doesn't really help with **fixing** the issue, but if you type `docker logs <container_name>`
you will at least find out why the container crashes...
Please post the logs, if you can't figure out where the problem is...

Comment: you can list all container (also the stopped ones) with `docker ps -a`